# errors for n-ary tree C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, tree

This is my first time working with any kind of tree. I created a tnode class for my tree and now I'm trying to create the class for the tree itself. However I've gotten a couple errors I can't figure out.

```
#ifndef Tree_Ntree_h
#define Tree_Ntree_h
// SIZE reprsents the max number of children a node can have
#define SIZE 10
// SEPERATE will allow the program to distinguish when a subtree no longer has children
#define SEPERATOR '@'
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template <typename T>
class tnode{
public:
T value;
tnode *child[SIZE];
tnode() {};
tnode<T> *addChild(T data){
    tnode*temp = new tnode;
    temp -> value = data;
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        temp -> child[i] = NULL;
    return temp;
}
};



template <typename T>
class Ntree{
private:
tnode<T> *root;
T data;
std::string filename;

public:

Ntree(){ root= NULL;}

Ntree( T data){ *root = data;}



inline T getRoot(){return root;}
```

My errors are in the last three lines.
In the last line of my code (getRoot), this is the error:

> No viable conversion from 'tnode > *' to
>   'std::__1::basic_string'

In the second to last line and the third to last line (*root = data) (root = NULL) this is the error:

> No viable overloaded '='

I don't understand why it is necessary to overload the = operator in this situation.

Comment: Why not use size as a template argument instead of a macro?

Comment: And your example contain many syntax error, like the class ntree does not end. Please correct the code so we can focus on the errors you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

`root` is a `tnode<T> *` and `getRoot` is returning a `T` object. The compiler doesn't know how to convert one to the other. You probably just want to return `root->value`

However, you haven't allocated any space for `root` and it might be `NULL`, so you need to determine what to do when it is NULL.

In this line:

```
Ntree( T data){ *root = data;}
```

This time you are assigning a `T` to a `tnode<T>`, which the compiler doesn't know how to do. You also haven't allocated any memory for `root`. Instead you probably want todo something like:

```
Ntree( T data){ root = new T; root->value = data;}
```

Or better still have a `tnode` constructor that takes a value.